# Record answer randomization in Qualtrics using javascript

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am making a survey in Qualtrics. This survey has a repeating question with six answer choices. The six choices are randomized (in the standard way, no javascript). The question is being repeated using loop&merge, which works great because it's the same question structure over and over (36 times), but I can use the field function to adjust the question and answers for every iteration.

However, one problem I am running into is that Qualtrics does not (as standard) support the recording of the randomization data in the results - i.e. how it has randomized the six answer choices in each iteration. When I use the 'Export Randomized Viewing Order data' function when downloading results, it only shows the answer order of the last time it asked the question. So it seems that this is a value that gets overwritten after each iteration.

So now I'm looking to record the answer order for each iteration through javascript.  However, I haven't found a function that gives the order answer (after randomization). I have consulted the [Qualtrics javascript API](https://eu.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/QuestionAPI/classes/Qualtrics%20JavaScript%20Question%20API.html) and found some functions that seem promising, such as getChoices (), but when I try this all I get back is the order of answers without randomization (i.e. just 1,2,3,4,5,6).

Does anyone know a way to record the randomized choice order for each iteration, using javascript or otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the thing here is to look at the order of choices in the DOM. Qualtrics provides the `getChoiceContainer()` method to get the div containing the choices.  Here's a snippet I wrote and minimally tested:

```js
//get the div containing the choices, then get all input child elements of that div
var choices = this.getChoiceContainer().getElementsByTagName("input");
//initialize an array for the IDs of the choices
var choiceIDs = []
//add the ID of each choice to the array
for (var i=0; i < choices.length; i++) {
 choiceIDs.push(choices[i].id);
  
}
//get the current choice order from embedded data and add this loop to it.
//Add a | to distinguish between loops.
var choiceOrder = "${e://field/choiceorder}" + choiceIDs.toString() + "|";
//set the embedded data with the new value
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("choiceorder", choiceOrder);
```

A couple of notes/caveats:
I only tested this on a basic multiple choice question with radio buttons. It may need to be adjusted for different question types.

I also just got the IDs of the question choices. You could probably modify it pretty easily to get other information, like the label of the choice, or the numeric value it corresponds to.

Comment: Thanks a million, that works perfectly! I added a few lines to take out all the extra characters that you get:

<code>var str = choiceIDs.toString();
str = str.replace(/QR~/g, "");
str = str.replace(/QID163~/g, "");(/code>

Answer (score 1):

I [found](http://sgmaldonado.com/main/tracking-order-qualtrics-loop-merge) a different way to record the loop and merge randomization order.

1. Create an embedded data field in survey flow. Here we will record the randomization order. I will call the field rand_order.
2. Add a loop and merge field with a unique number to identify each loop (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., n).

Then add the next javascript to any page of the looped block.

```
//*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/
   var questionText = "${lm://Field/1}"; // "${lm://Field/1}" will actually evaluate to  
   //whatever is Field 1 in the current Loop & Merge loop.
   // You can do this with embedded data too, as seen in the next line
   var order = "${e://Field/rand_order}" + "|" + questionText; // gets the value of the embedded data
   // field "rand_order", concatenates the current loop's identifier to it, 
  //and stores that as a variable
   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('rand_order', order); // updates the  
   //embeddeddata field "rand_order" to be our order variable, which has the current loop's 
   //identifier attached, effectively constructing a string of numbers representing the order
```

You will get a column with the name "rand_order" filled with "1|5|23|2...|n". You can change the separator to make more compatible with whatever script you are using to manipulate data.

Answer (score 1):

Qualtrics already records this information for you. It's just a matter of explicitly asking for it when you download your data. Number 5 on [this page](https://research-it.wharton.upenn.edu/news/qualtrics-hacks/) has more info, but I'll recount the important bits:

1. In the “Data & Analysis” tab, click “Export & Import” and then “Export Data”.
2. In the “Download Data Table” window click “More Options”.
3. Check the box for “Export viewing order data for randomized surveys”.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26160965)

Comment: @FedericoGrandi that's a good point, thanks. I've edited the answer accordingly.